# AngularJS PHP MYSQL Incorrect date displaying

Tags: angularjs, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am inserting timestamp in mysql database using doctrine ORM (string Annotation) and ZF2,

Creating timestamp using following

```
$date = new \DateTime("now");
$ts = $date->getTimestamp(); // 1374229715
```

MySQL varchar fields safely have 1374229715 timestamp in its varchar typed field.

When I check this timestamp(1374229715) using http://timestamptodate.com/?timestamp=1374229715
it return 19 Jul 2013 (which is correct).

But when I return this using angularJs.

```
{{item.created | date:'medium'}}
```

it displays

```
Jan 16, 1970 9:43:49 PM
```

which is incorrect.

Any idea why angularJs is doing this and Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP timestamps are in seconds whereas javascript timestamps are milliseconds, so you'll need to convert it, i.e:

```
{{item.created * 1000 | date:'medium'}}
```